# JMeter (unix version) segmentation fault seems dependent on loops/threads

Tags: java, jmeter, segmentation-fault

Running JMeter 5.3 headless from a command-line.  Using Cygwin.

Runs fine for sufficiently small input values for user-defined variables, but above those, I get this error:

Here is an example that failed.

## Using jmeter.sh

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t /git/web-performance-testing/DCS_login_dashboard_machine_actor_card_DTM.jmx  \
 -e -l /Users/xxx/OneDrive\ -\ Acme\ LTD/Load\ Testing/JMeter/dcs.jtl \
 -Jdashboard.threads=0 -Jdtm.threads=99 -Jdtm.rampup=5 -Jdtm.loops=100 \
 -Jmachine.threads=0 -Jdcs_user=xxx -Jdcs_password=xxxxxx \
 -o /Users/xxxx/OneDrive\ -\ Acme\ LTD\/Load\ Testing/JMeter/web_test_output/`date +%y%m%d_%H%M%s`  -f
```

```
./jmeter: line 208:  1236 Segmentation fault    
  "$JAVA_HOME/javapath/java" $ARGS $JVM_ARGS $JMETER_OPTS -jar "$PRGDIR/ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

And this one was fine:

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t /git/web-performance-testing/DCS_login_dashboard_machine_actor_card_DTM.jmx \
  -e -l /Users/xxxx/OneDrive\ -\ Acme\ LTD/Load\ Testing/JMeter/dcs.jtl \
 -Jdashboard.threads=0 -Jdtm.threads=99 -Jdtm.rampup=5 -Jdtm.loops=10 \
  -Jmachine.threads=0 -Jdcs_user=xxx-Jdcs_password=xxx \
 -o /Users/guyl/OneDrive\ -\ Acme\ LTD\/Load\ Testing/JMeter/web_test_output/`date +%y%m%d_%H%M%s`  -f
```

199 threads and 15 loops also worked - no segmentation fault.
20 loops - seg fault.
500 threads and 15 loops - no segmentation fault.

## Using jmeter.bat - different [better] result

Figured why not try the Windows version.  Very different results.
1000 threads - no problem.
1500 threads - not enough memory, but no segmentation fault. At least it's handled nicely.

[image]

Here is the basic structure of the JMX.

[image]